# Python function conditioned on number being even or odd

Tags: python, variables, if-statement, conditional-statements

I want to write a function that returns the lesser of two given numbers if both numbers are even, but returns the greater if one or both numbers are odd.

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem individually. A good way to show this effort is to include a [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Check the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) you finished before posting, especially [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Please post whatever you have tried till now after which I am sure many people will be ready to help you and will also help reduce the negative reputation :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `min` and `max` functions:

```
m, n = 1, 8

print(max(m, n) if m % 2 or n % 2 else min(m, n))
# 8
```